# Cannot conform to RandomAccessCollection due to Stride type

Tags: swift, containers, swift-protocols

I'm trying to make a collection that wraps another and vends out fixed-size sub-collections as the elements:

```
struct PartitionedCollection<C: RandomAccessCollection>: BidirectionalCollection {

    typealias TargetCollection = C

    let collection: C
    let wholePartitionCount: C.IndexDistance
    let stragglerPartitionCount: C.IndexDistance
    let span: C.IndexDistance

    init(on c: C, splittingEvery stride: C.IndexDistance) {
        let (q, r) = c.count.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: stride)
        collection = c
        wholePartitionCount = q
        stragglerPartitionCount = r.signum()
        span = stride
    }

    var startIndex: C.IndexDistance {
        return 0
    }
    var endIndex: C.IndexDistance {
        return wholePartitionCount + stragglerPartitionCount
    }

    subscript(i: C.IndexDistance) -> C.SubSequence {
        // If `C` was only a Collection, calls to `index` would be O(n) operations instead of O(1).
        let subStartIndex = collection.index(collection.startIndex, offsetBy: i * span)
        if let subEndIndex = collection.index(subStartIndex, offsetBy: span, limitedBy: collection.endIndex) {
            return collection[subStartIndex ..< subEndIndex]
        } else {
            return collection[subStartIndex...]
        }
    }

    func index(after i: C.IndexDistance) -> C.IndexDistance {
        return i.advanced(by: +1)
    }

    func index(before i: C.IndexDistance) -> C.IndexDistance {
        return i.advanced(by: -1)
    }

}
```

It seems that I can make this a `RandomAccessCollection`.  I changed the base protocol, and the playground compiler complained that the type doesn't conform to `Collection`, `BidirectionalCollection`, nor `RandomAccessCollection`.  I get offered Fix-It stubs for the last one.  The compiler adds 3 copies of:

```
var indices: CountableRange<C.IndexDistance>
```

Before I can erase two of the copies, all of them are flagged with:

```
Type 'C.IndexDistance.Stride' does not conform to protocol 'SignedInteger'
```

I keep the error even if I fill out the property:

```
var indices: CountableRange<C.IndexDistance> {
    return startIndex ..< endIndex
}
```

I thought `C.IndexDistance` is `Int`, which is its own `Stride` and should conform to `SignedInteger`.  What's going on?  Can I define a different type for `indices`?  Should I define some other members to get random-access (and which ones and how)?

I tried adding the `index(_:offsetBy:)` and `distance(from:to:)` methods; didn't help.  I tried changing `indices` to `Range<C.IndexDistance>`; didn't help either, it made the compiler disavow the type as `BidirectionalCollection` and `RandomAccessCollection`.

Comment: try `BidirectionalCollection where C.IndexDistance == Int`

Comment: You mean `RandomAccessCollection where C.IndexDistance == Int`.  I don't even need to keep `index(after:)` and `index(before:)`.  I don't know why it works, though.

Comment: Looks like you're just stretching associated type inference too far; defining `typealias Indices = DefaultRandomAccessIndices<PartitionedCollection>` works. Though I would prefer Leo's solution as the `IndexDistance` associated type is to be replaced by `Int` in Swift 4.1 anyway.

Comment: Btw, you could just make this a plain `Collection`, you would just need to define a custom index type such that it stores the start and end indices of the base collection to slice into, and then advance those indices on advancing the index (when conditional conformance hits, you'll then be able to do `extension PartitionedCollection : BidirectionalCollection where C : BidirectionalCollection`, same with `MutableCollection`, `RandomAccessCollection` etc.

Comment: @CTMacUser `RandomAccessCollection` [provides default implementations](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-4.1-branch/stdlib/public/core/RandomAccessCollection.swift#L176) for `index(after:)` & `index(before:)` in the particular case you mention, so that's why you don't need them :)